# How to make Password column in Sql Server 2008 case sensitive?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the login window, if password not matched then error must be shown.
All coding i have done but the problem is in Sql Server Password column it is not case sensitive and i donot know  how to implement this.

if a user has password `abc09Fd` and he typed the password in the format `ABC09fD`, SQL server makes him login. How to resolve this.

my table schema is

> create table Users
>   (
>   UserId int identity constraint PK_UserID primary key,
>   RoleId int constraint FK_Role_Users_RoleID foreign key references Roles(RoleId),
>   Username nvarchar(256) not null constraint U_Users_Username unique ,
>   Password nvarchar(256) not null
>   )

Comment: What does the query look like?  I'm guessing either code or the query itself is changing the credentials to lower case before query execution.

Comment: a stored procedure with 2 parameters `@username` and `@password`

Comment: You really shouldn't store the password. Have a look at storing a checksum of a password instead.

Comment: Perhaps using [hashbytes](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx)

Comment: got a solution since sql server is not case sensitive uing collate helps alot
 SELECT * FROM users
WHERE Username=@username and  Password = @password  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where a collation could come into play.

As others pointed out, note that storing passwords
in plain text is far from being a good idea.

```
SELECT [Password]
FROM [Users]
WHERE [Password] COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS = 'PaSSWord'
```

See also:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/rocks/2012/01/09/revised-difference-between-collation-sql_latin1_general_cp1_ci_as-and-latin1_general_ci_as/

Comment: Sorry bro already got the answer but thank for replying and after all msdn the big boss